# Open Android app using scheme

Tags: java, android

How can I open an Android app using an external app like this:

```
app://share/something?id=10&city=london
```

I already tried, without success:

```
<data android:scheme="myapp"  android:host="/share/something"/>
<data android:scheme="myapp"  android:host="/share/something" android:pathPattern=".*/.*" />
<data android:scheme="myapp"  android:path="/share/something"/>
<data android:scheme="myapp"  android:host="/share/something" android:pathPattern=".*" />
```

Is there any simpler way to handle this case?